# CSS Vertically Aligning Generated Plain-text

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to line up some plain text generated by an ng-for in Angular and I cant seem to get it to work.

I'm currently getting the result:

E |

A |

D |

G |

B |

E |

---7--

21-----

----20-

-----18

-5----

0-----

-19----

----16-

----22-

-----10

--9---

-----5

---14--

----21-

---13--

--4---

-19----

13-----

---18--

-----0

--15---

---17--

---4--

----1-

11-----

--24---

---2--

10-----

-21----

23-----

And I want the result to look like

E | -21

A | --

D | --

G | 7-

B | --

E | --

So vertically aligned for all rows.

I've been trying flex but I cant seem to figure out how to line things up.

Please help!

```css
.container-1{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box-1{
  flex:1
}

.container-2{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container-1">
    <div class="box-1">
        <div class="box-1">E |</div>
        <div class="box-1">A |</div>
        <div class="box-1">D |</div>
        <div class="box-1">G |</div>
        <div class="box-1">B |</div>
        <div class="box-1">E |</div>
      </div>
  <div class = "container-2" *ngFor="let currentTab of tabs;">
    <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 0; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock>{{currentTab.tab}}</ng-template>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock>-</ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 1; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock>{{currentTab.tab}}</ng-template>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock>-</ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 2; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock>{{currentTab.tab}}</ng-template>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock>-</ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 3; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock>{{currentTab.tab}}</ng-template>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock>-</ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 4; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock>{{currentTab.tab}}</ng-template>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock>-</ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 5; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock>{{currentTab.tab}}</ng-template>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock>-</ng-template>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `[align-items][1]` property of your `flex` container and set it to `center`.

```
.container-1 {
...
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
.container-1{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.box-1{
  flex:1;
}

.container-2{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container-1">
    <div class="box-1">
        <div class="box-1">E |</div>
        <div class="box-1">A |</div>
        <div class="box-1">D |</div>
        <div class="box-1">G |</div>
        <div class="box-1">B |</div>
        <div class="box-1">E |</div>
      </div>
  <div class = "container-2" *ngFor="let currentTab of tabs;">
    <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 0; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock>{{currentTab.tab}}</ng-template>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock>-</ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 1; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock>{{currentTab.tab}}</ng-template>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock>-</ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 2; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock>{{currentTab.tab}}</ng-template>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock>-</ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 3; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock>{{currentTab.tab}}</ng-template>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock>-</ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 4; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock>{{currentTab.tab}}</ng-template>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock>-</ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 5; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock>{{currentTab.tab}}</ng-template>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock>-</ng-template>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a hundred percent sure on what you want to achieve exactly.

I created borders around each div, so you can see the result. Please elaborate further on what it should do.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
}

.main div {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.container-2 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container-1">
    <div class="box-1">E |</div>
    <div class="box-1">A |</div>
    <div class="box-1">D |</div>
    <div class="box-1">G |</div>
    <div class="box-1">B |</div>
    <div class="box-1">E |</div>
  </div>
  <div class = "container-2" *ngFor="let currentTab of tabs;">
  <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 0; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
  <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock>{{currentTab.tab}}</ng-template>
  <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock>-</ng-template>
  <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 1; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
  <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock>{{currentTab.tab}}</ng-template>
  <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock>-</ng-template>
  <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 2; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
  <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock>{{currentTab.tab}}</ng-template>
  <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock>-</ng-template>
  <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 3; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
  <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock>{{currentTab.tab}}</ng-template>
  <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock>-</ng-template>
  <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 4; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
  <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock>{{currentTab.tab}}</ng-template>
  <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock>-</ng-template>
  <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 5; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
  <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock>{{currentTab.tab}}</ng-template>
  <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock>-</ng-template>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code for the desired result. It still has room for lot of improvement.

```css
.container-1 {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.box-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 4%;
}

.container-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 2%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container-1">
  <div class="box-1">
    <div>A |</div>
    <div>D |</div>
    <div>G |</div>
    <div>B |</div>
    <div>E |</div>
    <div>E |</div>
  </div>
  <div class = "container-2" *ngFor="let currentTab of this.tabs;">
    <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 0; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock><div>{{currentTab.tab}}</div></ng-template>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock><div>-</div></ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 1; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock><div>{{currentTab.tab}}</div></ng-template>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock><div>-</div></ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 2; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock><div>{{currentTab.tab}}</div></ng-template>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock><div>-</div></ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 3; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock><div>{{currentTab.tab}}</div></ng-template>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock><div>-</div></ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 4; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock><div>{{currentTab.tab}}</div></ng-template>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock><div>-</div></ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 5; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock><div>{{currentTab.tab}}</div></ng-template>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock><div>-</div></ng-template>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
.container-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.box-1{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box-1">E |</div>
    <div class="box-1">A |</div>
    <div class="box-1">D |</div>
    <div class="box-1">G |</div>
    <div class="box-1">B |</div>
    <div class="box-1">E |</div>
  </div>
<div class="container" *ngFor="let currentTab of tabs;">
  <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 0; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock>{{currentTab.tab}}</ng-template>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock>-</ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 1; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock>{{currentTab.tab}}</ng-template>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock>-</ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 2; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock>{{currentTab.tab}}</ng-template>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock>-</ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 3; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock>{{currentTab.tab}}</ng-template>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock>-</ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 4; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock>{{currentTab.tab}}</ng-template>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock>-</ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="currentTab.string == 5; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #thenBlock>{{currentTab.tab}}</ng-template>
    <ng-template class="box-1" #elseBlock>-</ng-template>
  </div>
</div>
```